# Xml parser in python without removing tags

Tags: python, xml, parsing, text

Working on XML-parser for my project but cannot deal with one problem.

This is the XML-file I have. I am interested in few elements: sentence, sentence certainty and ccue.
[image: XML]

As a desired output I want to get:
certainty, which is certain or uncertain
ccue, which is inside  tag, and
the whole sentence (with ccues — either including or excluding).

What I have done:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```
with open('myfile.xml', 'rt') as f:
tree = ET.parse(f)

for sentence in tree.iter('sentence'):
    certainty = sentence.attrib.get('certainty')
    ccue = sentence.find('ccue')
    if certainty and (ccue is not None):
       print('  %s :: %s :: %s' % (certainty, sentence.text, ccue.text))
    else:
       print('  %s ::,:: %s' % (certainty,sentence.text))
```

But in this case, ccues are removed from sentences and if the sentence is uncertain than it is not complete. the find-function stops as soon as it has found the ccue. So if the sentence is:

```
<sentence certainty="uncertain" id="S1867.3">However, the <ccue>majority of Israelis</ccue> find a comprehensive right of return for Palestinian refugees to be unacceptable.</sentence>
```

It will show me: "However, the" as a sentence.

Can anyone help me please to solve the issue? And you also could help me to save the result in CSV — it would be great.

UPDATED
The example of XML:

```
<sentence certainty="certain" id="S1867.2">Left-wing Israelis are open to compromise on the issue, by means such as the monetary reparations and family reunification initiatives offered by Ehud Barak at the Camp David 2000 summit.</sentence>
<sentence certainty="uncertain" id="S1867.3">However, the <ccue>majority of Israelis</ccue> find a comprehensive right of return for Palestinian refugees to be unacceptable.</sentence>
<sentence certainty="certain" id="S1867.4">The HonestReporting organization listed the following grounds for this opposition: Palestinian flight from Israel was not compelled, but voluntary.</sentence>
<sentence certainty="uncertain" id="S1867.5">After seven Arab nations declared war on Israel in 1948, <ccue>many Arab leaders</ccue> encouraged Palestinians to flee, in order to make it easier to rout the Jewish state.</sentence>
<sentence certainty="certain" id="S1867.6">This point, however, is a matter of some contention.</sentence>
```

Comment: Please post the xml sample... not a picture of the same.

Comment: @tdelaney added to the main message

Comment: You want the entire sentence, including the stuff in ccue? That's `''.join(sentence.itertext())`. BTW - posting shorter text (and far less political text) would help.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, sorry. I didn't think about it. And thank you! I will try your solution

Comment: @tdelaney yes, it helped. Thank you! Can you post it please as a separate answer that I could mark it as a solution?

Comment: I'll write up an answer. Did you want that `if` to read `if certainty=="uncertain" and (ccue is not None):`?

Comment: Yeah, I need the IF-statement but it will be adjusted a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XML, text can be broken into many `text()` nodes. `ElementTree` has a call to find all descendant text nodes so you can glue them together. There are ambiguities in XML about how whitespace surrounding text nodes should be handled (is it part of the real text or simply decoration for "pretty printing"). Your example has `text <ccue>text<ccue> text` (notice one too many spaces in there) so I am stripping them and adding my own space. You can tweak that part as needed.

```
# let elementree open and figure out encoding
tree = ET.parse('myfile.xml')

for sentence in tree.iter('sentence'):
    certainty = sentence.attrib.get('certainty', '')
    ccue = sentence.find('ccue')
    if certainty == "uncertain" and ccue:
       text = ' '.join(node.strip() for node in sentence.itertext())
       print('  %s :: %s :: %s' % (certainty, text, ccue.text))
    else:
       print('  %s ::,:: %s' % (certainty,sentence.text))
```